# zend form adding a class to a Htmltag

Tags: php, html, zend-framework

How can I go about adding a class to Html tag, I tried all different kinds of decorators methods but still can't come to a solution, here my preview html code Im trying to add a class to the li tag

```
<div class="col-md-12 field-box">
<dt id="firstname-label">
<dd id="firstname-element">
<input id="firstname" type="text" 1="Htmltag Array" 0="col-md-9 form-control" value="" name="firstname">
<ul class="errors">
<li>Value is required and can't be empty</li>
</ul>
</dd>
</div>
```

solutions tried

```
->addDecorator(array('row' => 'HtmlTag'), array('tag' => 'div','class' => 'col-md-12 field-box'), array('HtmlTag',array('tag' => 'li', 'class' =>'kopano')))

$firstName->setAttribs(array('class' => 'col-md-9 form-control',array('Htmltag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' =>'kopano'))));

$firstName->setAttribs(array('class' => 'col-md-9 form-control'),array('Htmltag', array('tag' => 'dd', 'class' =>'kopano')));
```

THANKS IN ADVANCE

Answer (score 0):

If you want set the class **'kopano'** to the **HtmlTag** of element **$firstName** try:

```
    $deco_html_tag = $firstName->getDecorator('HtmlTag');
    $deco_html_tag->setOption('class', 'kopano');
```

Comment: I want to put a class on the li tag, under ul so that it can be like this <ul class="errors">
<li class="kopano">Value is required and can't be empty</li>
</ul>

Answer (score 0):

Obviously, this is not possible without creating Helper. 
In Zend_View_Helper_FormErrors file the li tags are coded directly <li>

```
$deco_error_tag = $firstName->getDecorator('Errors');
$deco_error_tag->setOption('class', 'kopano');
```

But you can put in the ul tag:

And with Javascript, access to children ul tag